# Find with SQL query then update all columns in an array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. Previously I did this to destroy, but now I don't wanna destroy, but just mark them as `inactive` instead:

```
Shop.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]}.shops AS shops
  LEFT OUTER JOIN thirdparty.othershoplist AS other_shops
  ON shops.other_shop_id = other_shops.ShopID
  WHERE other_shops.ShopID IS NULL").map(&:destroy)
```

Now I don't want to destroy the records, but wanna set the column for `shop.shop_status` as `inactive` for the return set.

```
Shop.find_by_sql("SELECT id FROM #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]}.shops AS shops
  LEFT OUTER JOIN thirdparty.othershoplist AS other_shops
  ON shops.other_shop_id = other_shops.ShopID
  WHERE other_shops.ShopID IS NULL").update_all(shop_status: 'inactive')
```

But this is not working because the return set is an array. How can I achieve this as simple as possible (perhaps a one liner)?

Comment: For which records in your shop you are trying to update shop_status as inactive? I mean what is your `SQL` query?

Comment: Why not use sql 'update' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to leave that SQL query as is, I would do this:

```
ids = Shop.find_by_sql("SELECT id
       FROM #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]}.shops AS shops
       LEFT OUTER JOIN thirdparty.othershoplist AS other_shops
       ON shops.other_shop_id = other_shops.ShopID
       WHERE other_shops.ShopID IS NULL")
Shop.where(id: ids).update_all(shop_status: 'inactive')
```

Comment: Can't do it in one liner?

Comment: Well, you could put that big "Shop.find_by_sql" line where "ids" is in the second line and it would technically be one line.  Or you could rewrite that find_by_sql...

Comment: Care to give an example? Thanks.

Comment: @Victor - `ids = Shop.where(id: Shop.find_by_sql("SELECT id
       FROM #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config[:database]}.shops AS shops
       LEFT OUTER JOIN thirdparty.othershoplist AS other_shops
       ON shops.other_shop_id = other_shops.ShopID
       WHERE other_shops.ShopID IS NULL")).update_all(shop_status: 'inactive')` ... thats the one-liner